# Not able to see reports in SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a SharePoint site containing more than 100 reports.But i am not able to see few reports.When i browse the report it executes for 15 to 20 mins then it gives blank page with error at the bottom of the page. Details of the error is:

[image]

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2010 in reporting  integration mode?

Comment: yes.the error is occurring only for few reports.

Comment: First check your query if this working fine. After that delete the report, try to redeploy the reports. I think it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your report is timing out. Can you run the query behind the report in SQL Server Query Analyzer and optimize it?